# Updating node field value using custom module validation

Tags: 7, nodes

I currently have a custom module which calls a submit custom validation function. I am trying to update a value after the validation is run. Basically, if a value is present, update a field to say "Yes".

```
function sitefuncs_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

if( $form_id == 'stage_2_node_form') {
   $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'sitefuncs_custom_submit';
}

} // end hook_form_alter()

function sitefuncs_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {

        $banned = array(
        'better cures',
        'better nhs',
        'because it',
        'so what'
        );

  if (in_array($form_state['values']['field_stage_two_question_one']['und'][0]['value'], $banned)) { // if a banned word is the value of the input

$form_state['values']['field_stage_complete_text']['und'][0]['value'] = "No"; // set the value of the text input to No

} else {

$form_state['values']['field_stage_complete_text']['und'][0]['value'] = "Yes";

$messages = drupal_get_messages('status');
drupal_set_message(t('Your changes have been saved.'));

}

}
```

If anyone has any idea why the `$form_state` isn't updating the fields after I save the node, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that I was using

```
   $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'sitefuncs_custom_submit';
```

When it should have been

```
   $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'sitefuncs_custom_submit';
```

Then all my data saved using

```
$form_state['values']['field_stage_complete_text']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = 'No'; // set value to No
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) instead of alter the form.

> This hook is invoked from node_save() after the database query that
>   will insert the node into the node table is scheduled for execution,
>   after the type-specific hook_insert() is invoked, and after
>   field_attach_insert() is called.
>
> Note that when this hook is invoked, the changes have not yet been
>   written to the database, because a database transaction is still in
>   progress. The transaction is not finalized until the save operation is
>   entirely completed and node_save() goes out of scope. You should not
>   rely on data in the database at this time as it is not updated yet.
>   You should also note that any write/update database queries executed
>   from this hook are also not committed immediately. Check node_save()
>   and db_transaction() for more info.

**Example :**

```
function modulename_node_insert($node) {
  // Just change the node object and value will be saved.
}
```